# How to get the date by day of the week ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm creating rails app, and I need to put calendar into it. I have a json data which sending to app once in a week. JSON object has something like this:

```
route: "Monday"
```

or

```
route: "Saturday"
```

I need to put this day of the week as usual date(date calculated every week, since the day when the JSON was sent), for example JSON objects sent today, and to all of them I should give a date, routes: "Saturday" should give me 24-June-2017. Hope u understand my question :)

Comment: today (the day you asked the question) is 3 july, 2017. last saturday was july 1, 2017. the saturday before last was 24 june, 2017. so you want the date of a given day, one week prior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the current day in Rails, you can use:

```
Date.today
```

To get the previous Saturday (since today is `Monday 3rd July`, that's `Saturday 1st July`), you can use:

```
Date.today.beginning_of_week(:saturday)
```

Or, if what you actually wanted was the **previous** week's Saturday (`Saturday 24th June`), then you can use:

```
Date.today.weeks_ago(1).beginning_of_week(:saturday)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
1.week.ago.beginning_of_week(:saturday)
```

...However, note that the above will return an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object rather than a `Date` object - so will behave slightly differently.

Have a read through the rails documentation - in particular, the [`ActiveSupport` extensions to ruby's `Date` class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/Date.html) to see what methods are available.

If, for some reason, you needed to do this in pure `ruby` (i.e. without the above mentioned `ActiveSupport` extensions that come bundled with `rails`), then you could instead utilise the [`Date.parse` method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse):

```
require 'date'

Date.parse("Saturday") - 7
  # => Sat, 01 Jul 2017
```

---

In order to convert your `Date` (or similar) object to the string format you desire (`"24-June-2017"`), you can use ruby's [`strftime`](https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) method:

```
(Date.parse("Saturday") - 7).strftime('%d-%B-%Y')
```

In rails, it is a [common convention](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/Date.html#method-i-to_s) to place such custom date formats in a locale or initializer to avoid repetition. You can then reference this format by name:

```
# config/initializers/date_formats.rb
# (Call this whatever you want!)
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:calendar] = '%d-%B-%Y'

# Anywhere else in the rails app
Date.today.beginning_of_week(:saturday).to_s(:calendar)
  # => "01-July-2017"
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @TomLord answer:

One can check which day of the week it is, by using dedicated method [`monday?`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-monday-3F) to `saturday?`

e.g:

```
Date.today
# => Mon, 03 Jul 2017
Date.today.monday?
# => True
Date.today.saturday?
# => False
```

Comment: `"2017-07-03T00:00:00+00:00"` is not in the format `%Y-%m-%d`. Neither is the requested `"24-June-2017"`.

Comment: @TomLord `%Y-%m-%d` is **part** of the format RFC3339 (its the beginning). But it is not the format asked by OP I agree. I put this in the answer to indicate to other users than some format have been already define and there is no need to use `strftime()`. In this very case it is necessary though.

Comment: @TomLord I didnt saw that you edited your answer to add custom date with `strftime()` I've deleted the part on the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

When working with any built in packages in `Ruby` it is always a good idea to check out the documentation for available functions and examples. For time, `Ruby` comes with a convenient `Time` object which simplifies much of the interactions we do with `Time`.

For example, one can get the current time using:

`t = Time.now`, one can then do `(t + 1.days).monday?` or `(t + 2.days).day == 1.`

Days already have corresponding `int` values.

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Time.html

This documentation applies to the newest head, but you can find the version for your `ruby` with `ruby -v` and find the appropriate version because it does change over versions.

For your issue, you could have the URL use the string Monday and using a `switch case` or `hash` to derive the `int`eger difference from today, using this one could get the exact calendar date. Once it is parsed to `Time`, you could also do `Time.monday?..Time.sunday?`, which you may or may not find useful when trying to solve your problem. There are many ways to approach it, but difference from Today is a good solution and with how `Time` is able to add days like `Time.now + 7.days`, it feels natural using Ruby to do it in this way.